# make one item from gridview

Tags: android, gridview

i have a grid view which i want to select just one item, when i select another it will replace the first.
i try this but it still not working

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Send intent to SingleViewActivity
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#11db14"));
            avatarAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
            for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
                if(avatarAdapter.getSelectedPosition() != i);
                gridview.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("@null"));
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove ";" from:

```
if(avatarAdapter.getSelectedPosition() != i);
```

Comment: i find my error, Color.parseColor("@null") we cannot use that